MESA and glx errors when running glxinfo Ubuntu 24.04
System:

Windows 10 Host
Ubuntu 24.04 running in Oracle VM
Display set to VMSVGA

When I run the following:
glxinfo | grep OpenGL

I receive the following output:
MESA: error: ZINK: failed to choose pdev
glx: failed to create drisw screen
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20  
OpenGL ES profile extensions:

Can anyone shed any light on why I get the two errors:
MESA: error: ZINK: failed to choose pdev
glx: failed to create drisw screen

I've had a google and looked through the mesa packages but can't find anything useful.
Any pointers?
Thanks in advance.

same problem on bare metal

Same problem in WSL2 when launching Evince.

@user643722 - I updated last week and the problem (for me) has now disappeared.  I've no idea which package update fixed it, but I did see a number of mesa updates.  I'm on 24.04.1.  Running glxinfo | grep Mesa gives Mesa 24.3~git2409060600.1e8458~n if that is any use.

For the updated Ubuntu version of 24.04, it seems like the mesa drivers aren't fixed. The way that I fixed it was from  following this website.
https://itsfoss.com/install-mesa-ubuntu/
It seemed to work after I downloaded the new mesa driver.

Summarizing from the link in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1517172
The Kisak-mesa PPA provides the latest point release of Mesa. You can use it by entering the following commands one by one in the terminal:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade


Enable 3D Acceleration in Virtualbox Settings->Display
